# Как преобразовать окна QDialog (созданные в QT Designer) в QMessageBox?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

К основной программе хочу сделать дополнительные окна - About и т.п.
Создал окно QDialog в Дизайнере. Потом добавил в основной код:

```
class Message(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Message, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Но мне хотелось бы использовать готовые методы QMessageBox - critical, warning, information с их встроенными кнопками и иконками. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Я не понимаю Вашего вопроса, Вы хотите использовать готовые QMessageBox или Ваш диалог? Или хотите совместить и то и другое?

Comment: Я изначально хотел использовать QMessageBox, но его нельзя создать в Дизайнере. Если Использовать свой QDialog, то нужно вручную прописывать все что уже есть у Messagebox. Или же можно не прописывать вручную и как-то унаследоваться от QMessagebox? У меня в справке 2 больших текстовых портянки, пихать их в основной код совсем не хочется. Кроме того возможно понадобится как-то форматировать этот текст, а это удобнее делать в Дизайнере.

Comment: Вам придётся выбирать: либо узкий функционал QMessageBox, который позволяет изменить лишь малую часть внешнего вида. Либо QDialog, который позволяет изменить всё, что угодно и сделать внешний вид таким, как нужно. Совместить два подхода не удастся.

Comment: Меня устраивает узкий функционал QMessageBox, просто не хочется вручную расписывать длинную портянку. Пожалуй придется либо Диалог допилить до вида Messagebox, либо вручную в отдельном модуле писать стандартный QMessageBox с длинной текстовой портянкой.